# In CSS (specifically Bootstrap) parlance, what is a "well"?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I keep noticing `class="well"` in a web app using Twitter's Bootstrap, but I can't find any documentation about it, unless I just overlooked it.

Thanks.

Comment: Documentation @ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#wells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"well" is a CSS selector simply create prominent wrapper around element

```
.well {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The well is used as a simple effect on an element to give it an inset effect.

```
<div class="well">...</div>**
```